# Where Is device specific information kept on smart devices

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, emulation

I am doing a project for school on Emulation of device using its firmware. Using firmadyne, I can start up the smart device unfortunately because it is not a real device, information fields like Serial number, MAC address, and other device specific information is not present.  I have a shell, and I can look around a physical exemplar of the device but I can't find any place where that is stored. I am limited on what I can do (via busybox)

Where is the device specific information of smart devices usually kept?  I am assuming it is burned-in somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These information pieces are generally stored in the NVRAM (Non-Volatile RAM), which is stored in one of the flash partition. To emulate a device successfully, you generally have to fill up the NVRAM with valid settings.

Firmadyne contains an [NVRAM emulation](https://github.com/firmadyne/libnvram) and you can find more information about the problem itself in this [blog post](http://www.devttys0.com/2012/03/emulating-nvram-in-qemu/).

If I remember well, the NVRAM emulation could log out the requested settings, and you have to specify these values in the NVRAM storage directory.